# Breeze js query syntax for swift conversion

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, documentation, breeze, breeze-sharp

i'm currently working on a project with an existing breezejs api, and where going swift for IOS development, i'm trying to find the syntax for breeze query so that i can make a query Builder out of it.

I assumed that the syntax would have been the same as with OData v4 but i guess there is some minor changes to it that i can't seem's to figure.

I don't know if anyone as the documentation for this but it would be very helpful to port it to swift.

edit: what i got working so far...

**where clause** :

- $filter=(field eq 'somedata')
- $expand=fieldName1,fieldName2
- $select=(query)
- $orderby=id desc/asc
- $top=2
- $skip=18
- $inlineCount=allpages/none

Most of those are basic odata syntax as you can see from the [odata basic tutorial](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#count).

the only one that seem's to not be supported is $count and $search

**Edit:** It appears to be OData Microsoft style [Microsoft OData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541437.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the question Edit, the Breeze Syntaxe follow the odata-v3.